# Not getting updated data in email send marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am using journey builder object activity to update date and then I need to send the updated date in email. But even after waiting for 20 mins my email is not getting updated data.

Example, when event is fired journey gets started - wait for 1 day - update date to today + 10 -  wait for 25 mins - send the updated date email template

But I am not getting updated date in email template even though it is updated correctly in salesforce

Comment: Hi @Neha , if the data is getting updated correctly in Salesforce. Then there will be a problem in your ampscript only. Can you please share the ampscript used in email template as well so that it will be easy to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi Naveen, sorry I am new to marketing cloud and I dont know how to use amscript to bring data. I was doing some research on the same and I think I have to use lookup function but I am not aware of how to write ampscript in my email

Comment: No Problem, try to drill down on RetrieveSalesforceObjects Ampscript function. You can get the subscriber key by _subscriberkey attribute and use the above function to look for the date attribute from your object and pull it in email template.

Answer (score 1):

I have used following and it worked

%%[
SET @policyID = AttributeValue("Policy__c:Id") 
SET @policyDate = lookup("Policy__c_Salesforce", "Pending_Cancellation_Date__c", "Id", @policyID)
]%%
%%=v(@policyDate)=%%

where,
"Policy__c_Salesforce" // Synchronized data extension
@policyID // object ID from journey data
"Pending_Cancellation_Date__c" // The date I need in email template
"Id" // object ID from Synchronized data extension